# Teradata.Net.Data.Provider not support in Pivotal Cloud Foundry(PCF) environment

Tags: teradata

Teradata.Net.Data.Provider methods working as per expected in local environment. But after deploying it on PCF its throwing error while trying to interact with Tera data through Teradat.Net.Data.Provider methods.